# TcpClient/Listener: Do I have to call Sockets.Close when my program ends?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm using the `TcpClient` and `TcpListener` classes to establish a connection between two computers. I've read documentation and questions online, but can't seem to find the answer to this question:

Is it necessary to call `Sockets.Close()` before the program ends, or will VB close all sockets which were opened by the program for me before it ends? In addition, what if the program crashes?

From what I've seen, the suggested implementation of the `TcpClient` and `TcpListener` classes suggest closing the sockets in the `Finally` block so that they are closed even if any exceptions occur.

However, this finally block is not necessarily called if I just simply close the program by calling `End`, and I'm not entirely sure if it is called if a crash outside of the try block or on another thread occurs.

Comment: When your application exits the GC will call `Dispose()` on your `TcpClients` and `TcpListeners`. This will result in the underlying socket(s) also getting their `Dispose()` method called, which will close the socket and clean up unmanaged resources. So no, you don't need to call it yourself if you don't want to, but depending on how the endpoint works it might in some cases be a good thing to do anyway. -- If your application crashes the OS already keeps track of all resources used by your process, which will result in the OS releasing everything used by it.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Would you mind giving me a link or something which explains what you meant by 'depending on how the endpoint works'? I want to check just in case. Otherwise this saves a lot of hassle!

Comment: Well there's no documentation on how _your_ endpoint works (unless you've written one). What I meant is that perhaps the endpoint need to be aware of the connection termination before your app closes? It all depends.

Comment: @VisualVincent Ok, I understand what you mean — thanks!