# How to correctly terminate an application?

Tags: vb.net, garbage-collection, terminate

In the past I've usually added the following line to the `KeyDown` sub  in order to end my applications:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then End
```

However, upon reading the documentation on what `End` actually does, it turns out that it probably is one of the worst ways to end the application in terms of releasing resources, etc.

So now I'm trying to find the recommended way to terminate the application which will properly handle all resources, etc. I've found these two questions on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276069/how-to-exit-an-application-properly) and 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976380/net-end-vs-form-close-vs-application-exit-cleaner-way-to-close-ones-app)) but I can't conclude what the right answer actually is.

The accepted answer on the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276069/how-to-exit-an-application-properly) says that applying `Close()` to all forms is the correct way and will release all resources used correctly. This isn't convenient in applications with multiple forms, and further down `Application.Exit()` is suggested, and even:

```
Application.Exit()
End
```

which will definitely make sure the program ends even if the first line fails.

On the other hand, the accepted answer on the [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976380/net-end-vs-form-close-vs-application-exit-cleaner-way-to-close-ones-app) says "**you should never have to call `Application.Exit()` in a properly-designed application**", contradicting the above and an answer further down which says `Application.Exit()` calls `Close()` on all forms in later versions of .Net.

This has lead me to confusion — what is wrong with `Application.Exit()`?

If there is no problem with it, then am I right in thinking the best one to go with is:

```
Application.Exit()
End
```

or is that overdoing it? Otherwise, when does `Application.Exit()` fail to work (except when I write code which cancels it)?

Note: Although this question applies to all programs I make, including ones with multiple forms, I recently have started using Sockets (with the `TcpClient/Listener` classes) to make connections between computers and would appreciate any additional information relating to this when terminating the program in the middle of a connection. A comment in my [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946641/tcpclient-listener-do-i-have-to-call-sockets-close-when-my-program-ends?noredirect=1#comment65277271_38946641) assures me that calling `Socket.Close()` isn't even necessary, but now I realise that this may not be completely true since I was using `End` to terminate before.

Comment: `but now I realise that this may not be completely true since I was using End to terminate before` -If you call `End` execution will be terminated immediately and there will be no graceful Garbage Collection (everything will just be released by the OS). So yes, you are more or less required to call `Socket.Close()` if you want the connection to close gracefully when using `End`. **BUT** if you do use `End` there is also a chance that you might terminate execution _before_ the disposing of the socket is completed. It is not recommended to use `End` for application releases, only when debugging.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks, I guess I will avoid `End` then. btw why the question edit? This only applies to .net?

Comment: I removed "VB" from the title because it is unnecessary and recommended _not to_ write your language or tags there. Tagging the question with 'vb.net' is enough as that already indicates what language you use. See: [**Should questions include tags in their titles?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: @VisualVincent  Ok thanks, I'll keep that in mind in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application.Exit posts an exit message to all message loops for that application.

It's a perfectly acceptable way of closing an application and will cause all forms to attempt to shutdown. Individual forms can override this behaviour, for instance if they have unsaved work. This will leave your application running afterward so you need to decide if that needs to be handled.

Saying that I only use it if an external actor needs to shutdown my application. Otherwise I leave the app to exit when its main form closes.

You also need to consider the state of any foreground threads you have as these can allow all your forms to close but leave the thread processing in the background.

End is a very brute force technique and should be used as a last resot. A well designed application should be able to shutdown by closing the forms or by calling application.exit. I have used the approach in the past of launching a timer which will call End just before I call Application.Exit ... at least I give it a chance to complete gracefully.

**Note**: Application.Exit doesn't block. So `Application.Exit : End` might as well be `End` which is not ideal.

Here's the timer I use:

```
    Dim forceExitTimer = New Threading.Timer(Sub() End, Nothing, 2500, Timeout.Infinite)
    Application.Exit()
```

Comment: Thanks! I have just tried searching to no avail: does `Application.Exit()` ever fail to shutdown the application if you don't write any code which explicitly stops this?

Comment: Yes. A form can block it in its FormClosing event. Threads can also keep it open if you don't terminate them. It's mainly a signal to the app to shutdown gracefully, it's up to the developer to make that happen but it's not too difficult. See my note about the exit timer for something that will ensure it closes eventually.

Comment: Thanks, I will use the exit timer method then (I thought it did block).

Comment: By the way, will even Threads created by Tasks prevent it from shutting down if I don't deal with them?

Comment: No, they are background threads so don't block shutdown. Hence how I can use the `forceExitTimer` in my example

Comment: So as long as I don't use any foreground threads other than the main one, I won't have any problems with `Application.Exit()`?

Comment: You shouldn't need to but it is always best practice to attempt to dispose of anything you're using before shutdown.