# Should I use Imports or not?

Tags: vb.net

To avoid having unnecessary code in my program, I am wondering which choice should I use:

1. Use the statement like this `Imports System.Threading` and then use the code `Dim myTimer As Timer`
2. Do not use the statement `Imports System.Threading` at all, but use a full declaration like this: `Dim myTimer As System.Threading.Timer`

Both choices give the desired result, but I want to avoid adding all extra code from `System.Threading` that I do not need.

The question came to my mind when I saw the answer to the question here: [How to correctly terminate an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974613/how-to-correctly-terminate-an-application)
Here the user wrote `…Threading.Timer(…`, but didn't use `Threading` on the `Timeout.Infinite`.

Since I am using `System.Threading` in only one point in my code, which choice would be better?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't "add all extra code from `System.Threading`" if you use [`Imports`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/imports-statement-net-namespace-and-type). You just tell the compiler that you want to use that namespace, so you avoid always using the fully qualified namespace.

As a rule of thumb: use `Imports` whenever you need it at least once. Fully qualified namespaces don't make your code more readable, it's also harder to see what you use in this class if you omit the `Imports`.

You can use [Code Cleanup On Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CodeCleanupOnSave) to ensure that unused `Imports` are removed from your code when you save the file. But again, this is just removing redundant code, it will not improve performance or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (that I favour) is to use `Add Reference` and/or `Import Namespace` on the project's `References` tab rather than use `Imports` or fully-qualified names. Unless it's just a single instance or two, in which case I'll fully-qualify to tell me that I don't use this reference/namespace a lot in my code. It's just a preference. (Or should I say a "reference preference"? Perhaps not.)

Comment: I like having those "rules" only for myself that tell me small pieces of information that make my life easier. I will add yours to my list. Thank you.